# Correlate the instructions of the innerInstructions

Tags: transactions, instructions, transaction-instructions

I get the parsed transaction from Solana (getParsedTransaction) and I would like to specifically parse the instructions and their corresponding innerInstructions. How can I know that my innerInstruction[0] belongs to this or that instruction? Directly from the transaction, without any new RPC request. I can't find any index or simple information telling me that the innerInstruction is linked to such and such instruction. I hope I am clear in my question!

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ParsedInnerInstruction.index`](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/modules.html#ParsedInnerInstruction) should correspond to the index of the outer instruction that houses the inner instruction.

So if `parsedTransaction.meta.innerInstructions[0].index` is say 1, then it means the outer instruction is `parsedTransaction.transaction.message.instructions[1]` is the parent.